# connect to localhost in MySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to connect my MySQLWorkbench to localhost, so I can make a database. I have made the connection in the WorkBench, but everytime i test the connection I get a failure. The username and code is 100% correct. I also tried to make the port to 8888, but then workbench just goes in some kind of loop, where it is thinking all the time

I have made some screenshots of it, I hope anyone out there who can help me?

Best Regards
Mads

[image: MAMP Port]

[image: The connection I have made in the WorkBench]

[image: The error message]

*** EDIT: ***
I tried to delete the connection, and made it over again. This time it seems that I can connect now. I tried to make a database ´test´ which functions. As the screenshot shows, I afterwords tried to make a database ´examples´, where I get the error in the console:

"12:59:32   CREATE DATABASE `examples`  Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'examples'  0.000 sec"

[image: Succesful Connection]

[image: Error in Console]

Answer (score 0):

For general informations about creating connections in MySQL Workbench watch my Youtube video: http://youtu.be/DCgRF4KOYIY?list=PLWx5a9Tn2EvH0q2WXpUBqptxi5640qk9O. It shows what can go wrong with addresses and ports.

Generally speaking, make sure that the user you are connecting with has the proper rights to 1) connect from the given machine (see in the video sometimes localhost is not equal to the IPv4 loopback address 127.0.0.1) and 2) has the rights to create objects, query them and so on. The root user usually has these rights, but sometimes, with custom installations, it can happen this has been changed.